# itextsharp html to pdf - table border not working

Tags: itext, html-table, html-to-pdf

I am creating a page with TinyMCE editor and I need to convert content of editor into a PDF.
I am loading the editor with default content which contins `<p>` and `<div>` tags and one `<table>`.

I have tried to apply border to `<td>` and it is working but if I apply background-color to some `<td>` then in editors it seems perfect but in generated PDF I am not able to see bottom border of `<td>` which is above that `<td>` with background color.

```
strDetailtable.Append("<tr style='border:0;border-bottom-color:Black;border-bottom-width: 1px;border-bottom-style: solid;'>");
strDetailtable.Append("<td style='border:0;border-bottom-color:Black;border-bottom-width: 1px;border-bottom-style: solid;border-right-width: 1px;border-right-style: solid;width:200px;padding-bottom:5px;'>" + item.data1+ " </td>");
strDetailtable.Append("<td style='border:0;border-bottom-color:Black;border-bottom-width: 1px;border-bottom-style: solid;border-right-width: 1px;border-right-style: solid;width:200px;padding-bottom:5px;'>" + item.data2+ " </td>");
strDetailtable.Append("<td style='border:0;border-bottom-color:Black;border-bottom-width: 1px;border-bottom-style: solid;border-right-width: 1px;border-right-style: solid;width:200px;padding-bottom:5px;'>" + item.data3+ " </td>");
 strDetailtable.Append("</tr>");

strDetailtable.Append("<tr><td  colspan='3' style='background-color:#D9D9D9;font-weight:bold;border:0;border-bottom-width: 1px;border-bottom-style: solid;width:200px;padding-bottom:5px;padding-top:5px;'>" + item.headerdata + " </td></tr>");
```

Comment: What version of iTextSharp are you using?

Comment: These 3 dlls are used:
itextSharp 5.4.5.0
itextSharp.pdfa 5.4.5.0
itextsharp.xmlworker 5.4.5.0

Comment: Are you using XMLWorkerHelper to parse the html?

Comment: yes, using XMLWorkerHelper.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using XMLWorkerHelper to parse the Html you should not have problems, look at [conformance list](http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/itextdoc/CSS-conformance-list.htm) off css attribute supported, and tablecell border style attribute is supported; are you using HTMLWorker?

Comment: border is working but when i add background color to td i am not able to see bottom border of td above that, i also tried to give color to border of td.

Answer (score -1):

try
bgcolor='#004785' instead of background-color:#D9D9D9;
e.g. `<td bgcolor='#004785' style= ''>testing...</td>`